# Why do I get an error when building Solution in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, build

For a while now I've been getting the following OUTPUT window when building a solution:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Scheduler, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Scheduler -> C:\Users\dubilm\source\repos\scheduler\Scheduler\bin\Scheduler.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4811,5): error MSB3541: Files has invalid value "<<<<<<< HEAD". Illegal characters in path.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have tried Clean and Rebuild to no avail. The application works despite the reported error and updates have been deployed to production server with no issues. None of my other solutions/projects have any issues building.

The ERROR LIST window also lists the same error...

```
Severity          = Error
Code              =
Description       = Files has invalid value "<<<<<<< HEAD". Illegal characters in path.
Project           = Scheduler   
Path              = 
File              = 
Project Rank      = 1
Line              = 
Column            = 
Category          =
Source            = Build   
Suppression State = 
Tool
```

So no file indicated as the source of the error. The project is a web application .net vb MVC if this has any bearing.

Any suggestions of what else I can try to clear this error. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a certain file was merged wrongly. Use your source code control system (such as Git) to check your recent changes and the culprit should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <<<<<<< HEAD is what you get when trying to merge files, its used to indicate where the code starts (the old and the new one) sometimes when merging, some issues happen(ther could be a ton of diferent reasons) and you get stuck with that in the middle of your code, just use the search function (Ctrl + f) and search for <<<<<<< HEAD (make sure you had the search option in "search in this solution") you will see where it is, and if there is no duplicated code around, you can just erase it

Comment: Found it in the Solution/Project/Obj/Debug/Project.vbproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
Renamed the file .OLD and rebuilt the solution. This recreated the Project.vbproj.FileListAbsolute.txt file and no build errors. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the "bin" and "obj" folders and then cleaned the solution. It worked for me. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try unloading and reloading project. That worked for me.